# C++ beginners question how to access variables

Tags: c++, parameters, getline

So basicly my questions include when to use parameters and when I dont need them.
I try to learn from examples and this one I can't fully understand:
I will add the questions to the part where I dont understand something after "//" on the right side of the line. 
Maybe someone can give me a good explanation, what I need to do in which scenario or good sources where I can look this up on my own.

class Student with public attributes:

```
#include <iostream>


class Student
{
public:
    int stud_ID;
    char stud_Name[22];
    int stud_Age;
    };
```

function which I want included in int main():

```
void studentinformation(Student); //#1Why do I must include (Student) in this fuction?              ->  
                                  // If I dont add this parameter in here, there is no connection ->
                                  //to the function studentinformation(s) in int main.
                                  //Why exactly is that the case ?
```

main function to get information:

```
int main(){
    Student s;

    std::cout<<"Type in ID:";
    std::cin >> s.stud_ID;
    std::cout<<"Type in youre Name:";
    std::cin.ignore();   //
    std::cin.getline(s.stud_Name, 22); //#2 Why is std::getline(std::cin, s.stud_Name) not working ?->
    std::cout<<"Type in age:";         //#3 Or is there a better alternative ?
    std::cin >> s.stud_Age;

    studentinformation(s);             //#4 Why do I must include the parameter s ?
    return 0;

}
```

function to print information:

```
void studentinformation(Student s)  // #5 Why do I must include the Parameters ?
{   std::cout<<" Student information:"<< std::endl;
    std::cout<<" Student ID:" << s.stud_ID << std::endl;

    std::cout<<" Name:" <<  s.stud_Name<< std::endl;

    std::cout<<" Age:" << s.stud_Age<< std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Using the name `s` in both `main` and `studentinformation` is slightly misleading. Those are two different variables that happened to have the same name.

Comment: What is the `studentinformation` function supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `studentinformation()` is a free function with no connection to any instance of `Student` which is why you need to supply one as an argument.
2. `std::getline()` works on `std::string`s ...
3. ... and you'd be doing yourself a favour if you changed `char stud_Name[22];` to `std::string stud_Name;`.
4. For the same reason as in 1.
5. For the same reason as in 1. 1, 4 and 5 are questioning the same thing.

An alternative would be to make `studentinformation()` a `Student` member function instead. You could then call `s.studentinformation();` to print info about that particular student.

```
class Student {
public:
    int stud_ID;
    std::string stud_Name; // suggested change
    int stud_Age;

    void studentinformation() const { // const since the object (this) won't be altered
        std::cout << " Student information:" << '\n';
        std::cout << " Student ID:" << stud_ID << '\n';
        std::cout << " Name:" <<  stud_Name << '\n';
        std::cout << " Age:" << stud_Age << '\n';
    }    
};
```

Comment: @Silk • Even better if `void studentinformation(std::ostream& out) const {...` so different output streams could be passed in, and since the member method doesn't modify the state of the Student object it should be a `const` method.  (I know Ted already knows this.)  I'd also change the name of the method to `print`, but that's just my naming convention.

Comment: @Eljay Indeed, but I nevertheless forgot to make it `const`. :-) I'd add stream operators too but it felt like too much at this stage.